# iPhone - Array to UITableView

Tags: iphone, arrays, tableview

I can't display array in UITableView. The thing I do is - in viewWILLappear I'm creating array. In viewDIDappear I'm filling the array. But when I run `[myArr count]` or `[myArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` in table setup I get empty table. If I define constant integer as row count and some constant string as cell text everything works fine. Is there some populate() method I have to run or is it a problem with some order of declarations?

Thanks for any help. Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    myArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self load_array];
}
- (void) load_array {
  for (SomeObject *someObject in SomeObjects) {             
     [myArr addObject:someObject.someString];
     NSLog(@"Value: %@", [myArr objectAtIndex:([myArr count]-1)]); // works 
  }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [myArr count]; // works if I return const ("return 2")
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [myArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //=@"ASDF" works.
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What's in your .h file? myArr is declared as a NSMutableArray and not a NSArray? (Only asking because I've done this before). Also, have you properly synthesized myArr?

Comment: Yes, .h file is ok and myArr retained and synthesized. I believe it might have something to do with the fact that I'm getting my content from xml on server... I will check it soon, if it's true then the above code doesn't really help.

Comment: if you are retaining and synthesizing myarr, you should access it with self, e.g. self.myArr = (...) to prevent leaks. Otherwise, synthesizing would be obsolete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform `reloadData` on your table view to make the view re-load the table cells.

**Update:** You should not allocate your array in the viewWillAppear, as this method might be called several times. Construct the array in the `viewDidload:` and fill it there, or in a background thread, or in the `viewWillAppear:` (using a conditional statement to check if its already filled). You should also make sure that you do not create a memory leak, from the code you provided it is likely that `myArr` will be replaced by a newly allocated array without being released.

Comment: [uitableview reloadData]; anywhere in the code doesnt help, I tried it after adding all objects to array and even in separate method on button click.

Comment: Try NSLog(@"%i", [myArr count]); in the numberofrowsinsection to check if myArr has the right value, or set a breakpoint in that method.

Comment: Also make sure that myArr isn't leaking. Unless you don't release myArr in the viewDidDisappear, myArr will most probably be leaking. Have you considered setting up a property for myArr?

Comment: It equals 0, so it's wrong. But funny thing.. the Log appeared before another one that I used in viewWillLoad. So wtf? When I move all the "addObject" to viewDidLoad just after array init it seems to work but crashed just a sec later.

Comment: Try re-adding the reloadData method after filling the array and check the results of the NSLog. If it still returns 0, there is something wrong with your array. If it's not called, you are probably calling the method on the wrong object.

Comment: I think I know what's wrong more or less.. It's becuause apparently I was filling table too late. It works in viewWillAppear but for some reason doesn't work in viewDidAppear, even using reloadData.

Comment: Try putting a NSLog in viewWillAppear to check when this method is called. I'm not sure when this method is called in a table view, but it would replace your filled array with a new, empty one.

Comment: @TechZen There are no leaks, good point with alloc, but thing is - I want to refresh this array everytime I push this view (checking if there is new content online). I have changed the code a bit now in app. Will check later and give an update.

Comment: TechZen has only updated the formatting, the actual text came from me ;)